# Google webfonts and windows xp

Tags: fonts, windows-xp, google-webfonts

My site is utilizing google fonts, and I'm having some issues with XP.  Namely, because XP doesn't have anti-aliasing by default, all the fonts are pixelated, even in browsers like Firefox and Chrome.  Is there a way to correct this issue, or are XP users just stuck with it?

Comment: Same problem here. This is the main reason I am not using Google Fonts, even though standard fonts look pixelated as well.

Comment: Using cleartype rendering may solve the problem. http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion Tarun.  In the end, I went with Cufon.  It produced the most consistent look across all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

use SIRF! we all hate flash but this is the only feasible solution. And this issue is not restricted to windows XP, its the same case with all windows platforms.

Another option is to keep a text shadow of 1px 1px 1px on all fonts. This would make them appear a bit smoother.