# Google web fonts looks ok on Ubuntu 10, weird on Windows XP

Tags: windows, rendering, cleartype, google-webfonts

I'm having a weird problem with fonts on my website : I'm using Google's Web Font API, and it looks fine in every browser on Ubuntu, but looks weird in every browser on Windows XP, except IE8. I didn't have a chance to test it on Win7 yet.

My website on Ubuntu's Firefox 3.6.16 :

[image]

My website on Windows' Firefox 3.6.13 :

[image]

What is going on ? Is this simply a ClearType problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google webfonts and windows xp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185260/google-webfonts-and-windows-xp)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's just the way the platform and browser is rendering the typeface. The only way to see a more consistent way of rendering throughout browsers and platforms would be to use Cufón.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that font's GASP records are indicating it shouldn't be anti-aliased below a certain size.  I guess Linux/Ubuntu don't honor that.