# Stupid Jagged Looking Text in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-face

This question doesn't deal too much with coding itself, but if there's a fix for it in any way, do let me know. I've searched around for a while looking for an answer, as I've had this issue for a long time. Can anyone explain why this text in Chrome looks so terrible? This is just an example of some buttons on this website: [bad text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72VDg.png)

Each individual letter looks like it's a different size from the previous one, and nothing is smooth. It looks jagged and terrible. I've tried toggling on and off DirectWrite, but that hasn't changed anything. The text is like this on every site, not just StackOverflow of course. I hope this isn't how it's supposed to look...anyone?

Comment: That *does* look terrible - and no, it shouldn't look like that! However this isn't a programming question per-se (unless the question is about controlling such programatically, etc) so I've voted to migrated it to SuperUsers.

Comment: this is a long fixed bug on old versions of the chrome on windows. Try updating it. If it's up to date update your graphics card drivers. If that does not work too disable hw accerelation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the font for Chrome?

chrome://settings/ > show advanced settings >web content > customize fonts...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are a number of different fixes people have found helpful for this.

For one WordPress site I run, the problem was solved by loading a set of font files to our site and implementing @FontFace differently (some additional browser-specific settings and getting the sequence of those correct). This resolved the issue for all users without the need for any local changes to OS or Browser. Other folks have had success with a other CSS formatting settings.

Localised fixes include changing Chrome browser settings, and changing settings in Windows. Like the OP, I didn't find these helpful but others apparently have.

Edit - These Stack posts host a good discussion of the various options people have found helpful:

https://superuser.com/questions/308135/how-can-i-improve-font-appearance-in-google-chrome

[Jagged and choppy Google webfonts in Chrome and Firefox on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134306/jagged-and-choppy-google-webfonts-in-chrome-and-firefox-on-windows)

PS - @user2864740 In my opinion, the various CSS suggestions (@FontFace, -webkit-text-stroke: 0.25px, etc) do constitute a coding fix.